# sql convert to queryDsl

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I want to change the sql to querydsl.
But it's not going as well as I like, can you see what I'm missing?

SQL
[image]

Can I turn this query into Querydsl?

Comment: user have self-refrence ! thank you

Comment: Do you want to convert it to QueryDSL SQL or QueryDSL JPQL?

Comment: QueryDsl, actually now i'm using just nativeQuery in jpa! but i don't like this way(nativeQuery). thank you!

Comment: The first problem is that `ANY_VALUE` is not a supported function by JPA. You'd have to register a custom function for it (in both Hibernate and QueryDSL). The next problem, which is actually a bit more difficult, is that a subquery as from-node is not allowed in JPA. So this query can never be expressed in JPQL. You can use the `blaze-persistence-querydsl` extension to add support for this in QueryDSL/Hibernate: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/core/manual/en_US/index.html#querydsl-examples . It's very complicated stuff though.